I'm South African, my wife is German. My wife wants me to travel first before she and the kids come to Luxembourg. Is it possible?
My wife is a German citizen but we live in South Africa. Can I get a job as a truck driver and on what type of visa can I go to Luxembourg?

It would be much easier if she would come with you.

What types of visa have you researched so far? Do you have a commercial driver's license that meets to EU regulations?
